Salesforce API Upload document to an opportunity and convert file to a public url via Nodejs
I am tasked to fix a process on our node/express web server where we send in a base64 encoded file from our clients. We then upload the file to our opportunity files and we need to turn the file into a public url to store on a custom object in SF So we can pull the file to our clients to show customers. There is a chain of 6 network requests and i will explain them.

authenticate with sf api
upload file to the opportuity at /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion
create public url at /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentDistribution
query for content document id at /services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE ID = '${contentVersionIdFromCall2}'
query for distribution public url /services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT ContentDistribution.DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ContentDocumentId = '${call4Res.data.records[0].ContentDocumentId}'
put file url on our custom project files record

the issue is on call 3 we get an error message
[
  {
    message: 'duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>',
    errorCode: 'DUPLICATE_VALUE',
    fields: []
  }
]

but it doesnt give me the details i need to fix it with my lack of understanding whats going on.
Here is the code chain in javascript calling the apis.
const apiKey = getSFAccessTokenResponse.data.access_token
 
var PostFileToOppConfig = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://everlightsolar.my.salesforce-sites.com/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
      },
    data : postFileToOppData,
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity
};
 
axios(PostFileToOppConfig)
.then(function (response) {
    const contentVersionIdFromFile = response.data.id
 
    var ContentVersionIDData = JSON.stringify({
        "Name": documentTitle,
        "ContentVersionId": contentVersionIdFromFile
    });

    var ContentDistributionConfig = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://everlightsolar.my.salesforce-sites.com/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentDistribution',
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
        },
        data : ContentVersionIDData
    };

    axios(ContentDistributionConfig)
    .then(function (response) {
        // proceed to call number 4
    }.catch {}
}.catch{}

The issue i am having is when we send the ContentDistributionConfig. I get the duplicate error.
